# DDD: is it correct for a root aggregate to hold a reference to another root aggregate?

Tags: object-oriented, domain-driven-design

When following Domain-driven design (DDD), is it correct for a root aggregate to hold a reference to an internal entity that happens to be the root entity on a separate aggregate?

I believe this is not correct, mainly because of this rule on [the blue book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215):

> Nothing outside the AGGREGATE boundary can hold a reference to
>   anything inside, except to the root ENTITY. The root ENTITY can hand
>   references to the internal ENTITIES to other objects, but those
>   objects can use them only transiently, and they may not hold on to the
>   reference. The root may hand a copy of a VALUE OBJECT to another
>   object, and it doesn't matter what happens to it, because it's just a
>   VALUE and no longer will have any association with the AGGREGATE.

If a root aggregate holds a reference to another root aggregate the boundary of the former is violated and the whole concept of an aggregate is corrupted, so I believe if a root aggregate looks like needing to hold a reference to another root aggregate, then I need to create a **different** entity, that will probably share some of the same members as the other root entity, but will not have a global identity, as this other rule in the book states:

> Root ENTITIES have global identity. ENTITIES inside the boundary have
>   local identity, unique only within the AGGREGATE.

I believe this would be the correct way to go, but since it feels repetitive and redundant (when taken off the context of DDD, with pure OOP) I am asking for some feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by "internal entity (that happens to be the root entity on a separate aggregate)"?

Comment: FWIW, Anything may refer to an aggregate root entity as these are the things having global identity; whether the referrer is itself a root entity or not is immaterial.

Comment: As Erik said. Also, it doesn't matter if you reference it using ID or reference in your model. It both will convert to ID on the DB level and having a reference gives ORM ability to lazy-load the entity on demand.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might be overinterpreting the book. It basically says : anything outside an Aggregate cannot hold a reference to anything inside it except the root. Therefore, holding a reference to a root is legit. Holding a reference to a root doesn't mean it's part of your own aggregate and that you can control its invariants. It keeps its own invariants and autonomy.

However,

- A commonly accepted [good practice](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) is to refer to an AR by storing its ID, not a full reference.
- More modern approaches to aggregate design (see the [Red Book](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168)) advocate a cleaner separation between Aggregates. A business transaction should only change the state of a single Aggregate. Under this assumption,  the need to store a reference to another Aggregate tends to disappear because you're not going to modify 2 aggregates at the same time.

> is it correct for a root aggregate to hold a reference to an internal
>   entity that happens to be the root entity on a separate aggregate?

This never happens. A Value Object can be part of multiple Aggregates, but not an Entity. The reason is, nothing would then prevent you from sharing the same entity *instance* between Aggregates. Let's say that entity instance E belongs to both aggregate instances A and B. Since the premise of DDD is that the Aggregate is the entry point, you would be able to load A, modify entity E through it, all the while silently violating invariants from B (that you didn't load).

See the answer from Greg Young here : http://domain-driven-design.3010926.n2.nabble.com/Can-an-Entity-be-Shared-across-many-Aggregates-td7579277.html

Comment: Thank you Guillaume for the clear, concise and insightful answer. True DDD connoisseur's savoir-faire. This is what I was looking for. Chapeau!

Comment: I know it may be a silly question, But could I ask what's the meaning of `holding a reference` in this context ? because I confused when you said that : `holding a reference to a root is legit` then after that you said:`This never happens. A Value Object can be part of multiple Aggregates, but not an Entity. The reason is, nothing would then prevent you from sharing the same entity instance between Aggregates.`

Comment: Hold a reference = keep it internally/durably, as a member of the class. The dichotomy here is root vs non-root. You can hold on to a root reference but not a non-root reference.

Comment: @guillaume31 thanks a lot, but Could I ask if Is it okay to keep an `id` of internal entity(not-root) in to another aggregate or this violates whether (root or not) ?

Comment: What would you do with that ID? Even repositories only give you roots, not internal entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregate root object should (generally) only have properties which are part of its domain.

If you have an AR object with a property which is not in the aggregate then you are immediately faced with the question. 'Why not?'

You could add the Id of the other object perhaps? Or inject a repository?

But it sounds like you should add a cross domain service which references both root objects and performs the required logic

Comment: Ewan, I was thinking more of reusing a class between two different aggregations in the sense of OOP, rather than having a domain service acting as a business script that will be doing some work with the two different DDD aggregates. In conclusion I concur with you, my aggregate root should only have properties which are part of its domain.